# No string is returned from static function C#

Tags: c#, winforms, static, return-value, monthcalendar

Hello I trying to make a function wich will shof a calender at a givven location on a given form and the returns the selected date in a string.

This is what i've got so far:

```
public static string ShowCalendar(Point locatieCalender, Form F1)
    {
        MonthCalendar calender = new MonthCalendar();
        calender.Location = locatieCalender;
        calender.Show();
        calender.Visible = true;
        calender.BringToFront();
        calender.Parent = F1;
        string date = calender.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString();
        DateTime dateValue = DateTime.Parse(date);
        string dateForTextbox = dateValue.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

        //calender.Hide();
        return dateForTextbox;

    }
```

And the function call looks like this:

```
Point calenderLocatie = new Point(405, 69);
        string dateForTextbox = HelpFunction.ShowCalendar(calenderLocatie, this);
        txtPeriode_Tot.Text = dateForTextbox;
```

The calender shows on the form but no string is returned. I've tried a event handler but because of the static property this doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Did you try setting a breakpoint and walktrough the static method? Breakpoints always come in very handy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ShowCalendar` method can't return a string that way, I understand that you want to show the calendar, let user select some date and hide it after that, store the selected date in a string, here is what it should be:

```
public static void ShowCalendar(Point locatieCalender, Form F1, Control textBox)
{
    MonthCalendar calender = new MonthCalendar();
    calender.Location = locatieCalender;
    calender.Parent = F1;
    //Register this event handler to assign the selected date accordingly to your textBox
    calendar.DateSelected += (s,e) => {
      textBox.Text = e.Start.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
      (s as MonthCalendar).Parent = null;
      (s as MonthCalendar).Dispose();          
    };
    calender.Show();
    calender.BringToFront();
}
//Use it
Point calenderLocatie = new Point(405, 69);
HelpFunction.ShowCalendar(calenderLocatie, this, txtPeriode_Tot);
```

Comment: Yes This Works!! Could you explain what the Arrow does and (s,e)? Please  (-:

Comment: @user2726516 that's part of `lambda expression`. You may want to search more on that. `(s,e)` is `argument part`, a `DateSelected` event handler has 2 arguments, the part `=>{...}` defines the code of the event handler. In fact we can define a separate method such as named `DateSelected_Handler`, then do this: `calender.DateSelected += DateSelected_Handler`, however the **signature** of the `DateSelected_Handler` should be appropriate taking 2 arguments of `object` and `DateSelectedEventArgs`.

Answer (score 0):

You need a handler for this. Remove the static keyword from the method.